# CSV show a specific row

Tags: php, csv, row

I'm new here, I'm trying to get a Specific row for CSV but could not actually get it, hoping someone could help me.

Here is a Example of my CSV.

```
Aaron, Male, aaron@website.com
Arianne, Female, arianne@something.com
Bea, Female, bea@hello.com
Carlos, Male, carlos@website.com
Drake, Male, drake@website.com
Delilah, Female, del@hello.com
Erica, Female, erika@webisite.com
Flint, Male, flint@something.com
```

I wanted to only show a row from drake to erica in my file.

Here is the sample of my code

```
 <?php
echo "<html><body><table BORDER=1, WIDTH=1200px>\n\n";
$f = fopen("Senter code hereample.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}`enter code here
fclose($f);


echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: A single line: `$line[number_here]`.

Comment: Would need to be an array de-referenced (assuming PHP 5.4+) call to `fgetcsv($f)[number_here]`. `$line` is just a pointer during the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table BORDER=1, WIDTH=1200px>\n\n";
$f = fopen("file.csv", "r");
$i = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false){
    $i ++;
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        if ($i==5 ||$i==6||$i==7)
        echo "<td>".$i.' - '. htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Tested and working.

Comment: Should just use a `for` loop with `count()` instead.

Comment: what if I added another column, lets say "brock, male, brock@mail.com", the number 5 will be carlos and 7 will be delilah

Comment: @Hayder-Abbass Help please

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example where you want to show Drake, Delilah and Erica you can do this:

```
$csv_lines = file('yourcsv.csv');

echo $csv_lines[4]; // Drake, Male, drake@website.com
echo $csv_lines[5]; // Delilah, Female, del@hello.com
echo $csv_lines[6]; // Erica, Female, erika@webisite.com
```

If your CSV is dynamic and you want to search for those names instead of referring to them by their exact line number, which is probably a better way to do it, you could do something like this:

```
$csv_lines = file('yourcsv.csv');

// Filter out anything that isn't the right first name
$csv_lines = array_filter($csv_lines, function($value) {
    /// Split up the line and trim each result
    $line_bits = array_map('trim', explode(',', $value));
    // If the first name is in your array, return this value otherwise strip it
    return in_array($line_bits[0], array('Drake', 'Delilah', 'Erica'));
});
```

A dump of the array then returns:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Drake, Male, drake@website.com
    [5] => Delilah, Female, del@hello.com
    [6] => Erica, Female, erika@webisite.com
)
```

**Note:** using [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) is a quick and easy way to read a file into an array, but it shouldn't be used if your file is large as the entire file needs to be loaded into memory before it can be parsed. In this case it is appropriate, but massive files should be approached line by line instead.

[Here's a demo](https://eval.in/184303) of both of these examples. (*Note:* `file()` is substituted for `explode()` by new line in this example).